# How to work around HP printer cartridge expiry?

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

In 11.04 version of Ubuntu my printer worked fine with expired cartridges.

It seems that the new 12.04 LTS version contains some driver changes as now the printer stops with "cartridge error" signs for the expired cartridges.

Do you know how to configure / change the driver to avoid this? I need only black and white printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to Printing from the dashboardand and selecting the printer I was able to change its driver to HP > Business Inkjet 1100d > hpijs
That one works. The hpcups driver (the default) doesn't work with expired cartridges.